# Short intervals containing a prescribed number of primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

In [arXiv:1802.10327](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.10327), the following conjecture appears:
$$\vert\{n\leq x,\vert [ n,n+\lambda\log n]\cap\mathbb{P}\vert=m\}\vert\sim\frac{\lambda^{m}e^{-\lambda}}{m ! }\cdot x$$
Differentiating the expression on the right-hand side with respect to $\lambda$ shows that it is maximal when $\lambda = m$.

Assuming that the left-hand side is $\sim C_{\lambda,m}x$, can it be proven unconditionally that $C_{\lambda,m}$ is maximal when $\lambda = m$?

Comment: It should be $\lambda \log n$ on the LHS.

Comment: Just as a remark, as noted here https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0606408 the conjecture follows from the Hardy-Littlewood conjecture on the distribution of tuples of primes.

Comment: By the way, let  $f(\lambda,m)=\frac{\lambda^m.e^{-\lambda}}{m ! } $ and  $ g(\lambda,m).x $ the LHS of the conjectured asymptotics above. Denote by  $d(f,g) : =\sup_{\lambda,m}\{\vert f(\lambda,m)-g(\lambda,m)\vert\} $. Can it be proven that the latter tends to  $ 0 $ as  $ x $ tends to  $ \infty $?

Comment: A possible way to tackle this problem would be to associate to  $ g $ an entropy  $ S(g) $ and show this entropy is an increasing function of  $ x $.